# Using permutation with int arrays (C)

Tags: c, arrays

The following code has the user input the length of the first array, then takes in the values of the first array. After this, the code takes in the values for a second array that is one size smaller than the initial array. After finding these values, the code then permutes both arrays. However the second array keeps failing to permute correctly, can anyone tell me why?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #define N 12
 #define M 11

 int print(int *arr, int n)
 {
 int i;
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf(“\n”);
    }


 int main()
 {
  int count = 0;
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  if (n>12)
  {
  printf("Please choose a      number less than or equal to 12");    
 return 0;
 }
 int i, j;
 int arr[N];
 int bok[M];
 int temp;
 int k=n-1;
 for (int i = 0 ; i < n; ++i)
 {

scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
}
for (int i=0; i < k; ++i)
 {
   scanf("%d", &bok[i]);
   }
   for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1] = temp;
        print(arr, n);
     }
     }
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)                  {
        temp = bok[i];
        bok[i] = bok[i+1];
        bok[i+1] = temp;
        print(bok, n);
       }
     }
   return 0;
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of how it should work and how it actually work ?

Comment: input:5->1,2,3,4,5->1,2,3,4

Comment: Then all possible combinations of those groups of numbers should print out

Comment: do you mean something like [this](https://www.codesdope.com/blog/article/generating-permutations-of-all-elements-of-an-arra/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the second array is one smaller than the first, it has `n-1` elements, and the index of its last assigned element is `n-2`. A loop `for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)` is used, which iterates `i` to a maximum value of `n-2`. Then, inside the loop, `bok[i+1]` is accessed. When `i` has the value `n-2`, this is `bok[n-2+1]` = `bok[n-1]`. But that is beyond the last assigned element of `bok`, which is `bok[n-2]`.

It appears you intend `k` to represent `n-1`. Given this, every instance of `n` in the second set of permutation code should be changed to `k`.

If the code is intended to print every permutation of the numbers, it is incomplete; the algorithm apparently intended cannot do the job.

Comment: Thank you! What functions do I need to add?